# How to un-link a CMS user from a contact (and re-link to another contact)?

Tags: user-account, cms-integration

If you have a contact with a linked CMS user, sometimes you want to un-link them and re-link the CMS user to another contact.

The way I've figured out to do this without having to directly change anything in the database is to create a duplicate contact for the contact you want to un-link, merge this contact with the original contact as the duplicate (moving everything to the new contact except the CMS user), then doing Synchronize Users to Contacts and finally merging the newly created contact with the contact you want the CMS user to be linked to. But that's messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping for CMS user to Civi contact is the `UFMatch` entity.

You can use APIv4 Explorer to view and change these.  If you have one that is wrong, just delete the corresponding UFMatch.  When the user logins in next time a new match will be created based on the CMS email address.

If you have multiple Civi contacts with the same email address you might need to create/modify a UFMatch but often just deleting the existing one is sufficient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Merging the two civi records should give you the ability to have the CMS user transferred from A to B.